# Splitting a string into multiple arrays based on length (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, split

I have a string which can be of variable length, for this question I will keep it simply and assume a small subset of items in the list.

The objective is to split the string to create multiple string values where the length is greater than 11, however I would need to preserve the comma values (e.g. I can't just split every 11 characters, I must split at the last comma before the 11th character

```
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5
```

For arguments sake, lets propose the max length of the string can be 10 characters, so in this example  the above would be converted to three separate strings:

```
test1,test2

test3,test4

test5
```

To clarify there is a maximum allowed character limit of 11 characters per split value, but we want to use these as efficiently as possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jb31 I've tried a number of different Regex patterns and loops, but I'm finding it difficult to come up with a solution which is clean and works regardless of the input value.

Comment: But `test1,test2` is 11 characters, not 10 characters? (same with `test3,test4`) Why do you want them output if they're more than the allowed length?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Good point, lets say every 11 characters, but in the case of every 10 characters, the rule should work but we would get a different output. The actual use case is on 255 character string lengths, but I lowered it for ease of answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ( when you want to treat as 10 as min length and want to continue upto to the next upcoming , or end of string )

```
(.{10,}?)(?:,|$)
```

[image]

```js
const input = 'test1,test2,test3,test4,test5';
console.log(
  input.split(/(.{10,}?)(?:,|$)/g).filter(Boolean)
);
```

---

***Update:-*** Since you want the value in between a range you can use this

```
(.{1,22})(?:,|$)
```

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/CmA3qW/3/)

Comment: What tool did you use to create this image?

Comment: @CodeManiac - Awesome image

Comment: This does not really work. Try it with `12`, result will be `["test1,test2,test3","test4,test5"]`.

Comment: @str `The objective is to split the string to create multiple string values where the length is greater than 11, however I would need to preserve the comma values` i am interpreting it as least length should be 11 and continue upto next comma, ( initially it was mentioned 10 instead of 11 )

Comment: @CodeManiac "*The actual use case is on 255 character string lengths*".

Comment: @CodeManiac Essentially there is a maximum character limit of X per array value. So if this value was changed to another number the solution would still work. For example if we set this limit to 255 it will work. So str is right, when you select 12 the first string set exceeds the maximum allowed value

Comment: @CorbinSpicer is [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/CmA3qW/2/) what you're looking for ? try changing the value in `{1,21}` to see it enough for all your cases or not

Comment: @CodeManiac That's perfect!

Comment: @str thanks for your feedback mate, updated my answer accordingly,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for something like this. But this code gives the output according to your example :

```
// Try edit msg
var msg = 'test1,test2,test3,test4,test5'

msgs = msg.split(",")

final = []
str = ""
msgs.map( m => {
  str += str == "" ? m : "," + m
  if (str.length > 10){
    final.push(str)
    str = ""
  }
})
final.push(str)
console.log(final)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
"test1,test2" ,
"test3,test4" ,
"test5"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression to match a non-comma, followed by up to 8 characters, followed by another non-comma, and lookahead for either a comma or the end of the string:

```js
const input = 'test1,test2,test3,test4,test5';
console.log(
  input.match(/[^,].{0,8}[^,](?=,|$)/g)
);
```

Because in the given input, `test1,test2` (and any other combination of multiple items) will be length 11 or more, they won't be included.

If you want to allow length 11 as well, then change `{0,8}` to `{0,9}`:

```js
const input = 'test1,test2,test3,test4,test5';
console.log(
  input.match(/[^,].{0,9}[^,](?=,|$)/g)
);
```

If there might be items of length 1, make everything matched after the first non-comma optional in a non-capturing group:

```js
const input = 'test1,test2,test3,test4,t';
console.log(
  input.match(/[^,](?:.{0,9}[^,])?(?=,|$)/g)
);
```